# How to use escape symbol in insert query (ORACLE)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to read about Escape Symbol from net but not able to find perfect answer with example for insert query .

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What "escape symbol" are you talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are searching for [alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm):

```
INSERT INTO tab(t) VALUES (q'{This text contains ' inside string}');
-- alternative double '
INSERT INTO tab(t) VALUES ('Second '' example ');
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=46b3a4b65ce7f2712f7abab4fdc1bc93)**